# int to bool casting

Tags: c++, casting, boolean, int, warnings

In VS 10 I get a warning:

```
warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false' (performance warning)
```

trying to compile

```
int x ;
static_cast<bool>(x);
```

How is it possible to write a code which doesn`t cause this warning?

Comment: It is not an error, it is a warning.

Comment: On a different note, the code, as shown, will lead to *undefined behavior*. The code shows `x` being defined without an initializer, which means `x` will have an *indeterminate* value. Using indeterminate values in any way leads to the above mentioned UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int x ;
bool b1 = !!x;  // common idiom; get used to it.  "Newcomers" just need to learn the idiom.
bool b2 = x!=0; // another way, less idiomatic
```

Answer (score 9):

How about something this:

```
x != 0
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a stupid warning and can be ignored/disabled. There is no performance issue as far as I know.