# if statement with explicit static_cast to bool

Tags: c++

Does `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` make sense for some type of x?

Obviously if `x` is a `bool`, `static_cast` is not required.

If `x` is a raw pointer or `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`, then `if (x)` is alright (especially since `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` both have a `bool` operator). Maybe `if (x != nullptr)` might be better.

If `x` is an `int`, I guess `if (x != 0)` is preferred.

If `x` is a `double`, I guess `if (x != 0.0)` is preferred (although checking for exact floating point values has its own issues).

If `x` is some enum, `if (x != E())` or `if (x != E::whatever)` probably is better than `static_cast<bool>`.

Are there any reasons to use `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` for custom types (structs or classes) convertible to `bool`?

AFAIK the C++ Core Guidelines do not mention `static_cast<bool>` explicitly. I'm aware of following discussions:
[if (static_cast<bool>(x)) vs if (x)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674726/if-static-castboolx-vs-if-x) (which covers pointers only) and
[int to bool casting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14242218/int-to-bool-casting)

Comment: ... but then again, not in the context of `if` which will use the `explicit operator bool` without the the need for a cast.

Comment: In an `if`, `while`, or `for` statement, the controlling expression is ["contextually converted to `bool`"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). In that context there is no need for a cast, even if the type has a conversion to `bool` that's marked `explicit`.

Comment: `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` is equivalent to `if (x)`, even for types with `explicit operator bool`.

Comment: I guess you might if you're interacting with a C API that return truth values as `int` ? `if(static_cast<bool>(selected))` is probably no worse than `if(selected != 0)` (what does selected equals to 0 means?) in this case. But the preferred way would be simply `if(selected)`.

Comment: "If `x` is some enum, `if (x != my_enum::whatever)` probably is better than `static_cast<bool>`." -> there might not be an enumeration in the enum with value 0 though, so your "probably better" style might not be an option.  `if (my_enum)` - for an enum class - won't compile without the `static_cast`.

Comment: @Tony If `my_enum` has no value equal to 0, then no instance of that enum should ever be 0. — You *could* still create one using `my_enum()`, but you can then also do the same in the comparison inside the `if` conditional.

Comment: how is this different from https://stackoverflow.com/q/58674726/4117728 ? "Covers pointers only" is the answers, but that doesnt really make this a different question

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "no instance of that enum should" - perhaps in the world of your own coding standards, but that's not inherent in C++.  `my_enum{}` creates exactly such an instance.  As a concrete example of when a zero value might be valid but having no need of a matching enumeration  - if the enum is used to store a bitwise OR of 2^N flag values (i.e. 1, 2, 4, 8...), there may be no more reason to insist of a zero value than any multi-bit value such as 3, 5, 6, 7, 9 etc.

Comment: @TonyDelroy You seem to have read only the first sentence of my comment, not the rest, which already addresses this.

Comment: @TonyDelroy the enumerators is only the named values of the enum type, but the underlying type has many more values. Im not even sure if you can define an enum which has not `0` within its range

Comment: @KonradRudolph: "already addresses this" - you address that a 0 value *could* be created without an enumeration, but only after asserting that instances *should* never have such a value: it's that "should" part that I was contesting, with an illustrative use case.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Are there any reasons to use `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` for custom types (`struct`s or `class`es) convertible to `bool`?

Not often. Even `class`es only explicitly convertible to `bool` will convert to `bool` in that context.

```cpp
struct Foo {
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
};

int main() {
    Foo f;
    if(f) {}    // compiles fine
}
```

If you however have a class with multiple user-defined conversions ...

```
struct Foo {
    explicit operator bool() const { return true; }
    operator int() const { return 0; }              // risky non-explicit
};
```

... you may want to clarify exactly which one you aim to use.

Comment: Even for evil `Foo`, it is unneeded [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/fPrarjojq).

Comment: @Jarod42 :-) I know. The aim was for clarity. It could be a messy class where people add and remove `operator`s and suddenly `bool` is gone and then the implicit  `int` kicks in.

Comment: @TedLyngmo: But `static_cast<bool>` will happily chain a user-defined conversion to `int` followed by a standard conversion to `bool`, just like the contextual conversion would.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, it's for clarity of the intent for the reader of the code, but sure, the evil implicit conversion will still kick in. The only hope is that the explicit `static_cast` makes someone pay extra attention there when searching for the bug. :)

Answer (score 18):

> Does `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` make sense for some type of x?

Yes for enum class:

```
enum class E {
    A = 1
};

E e = E::A;
if (e) {} // KO
if (static_cast<bool>(e)) {} // OK
```

For regular struct/classes, `if (static_cast<bool>(x))` is equivalent to `if (x)`, even for types with `explicit operator bool`, so you can use the later.

Comment: This is of course the right answer. Can't believe I didn't think of that case. I've used it a lot :-)

Comment: Besides arguably being a questionable enum class, wouldn’t you prefer an explicit check here, same as for `int` (i.e. `if (e != E())`? I know *I* would.

Comment: Thanks, @KonradRudolph, I didn't have this option in mind comparing some enum value to a zero-initialized one. I edited my question, adding your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, @Jarod42, for pointing out that enum classes cannot be used like traditional enums in `if` statements.

Comment: `explicit operator bool` applies to other contexts similar to `if()`, notably `while()` and the second component of `for(;;)`.

Comment: Can you please add a reference for this behavior?